# Modal rendering several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are developing an application which is for restaurants. The dishes can have variations (medium rare or an ice-cream flavor for example) and in the Order view, we can also increment order-items with variations. 
The problem I am having is that the modal for choosing the variations renders several times, and therefore the last element is always chosen when adding a new dish with variations.

My code for the modal looks like this:

```
    getDish(dish){
    const extraId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);  
    if(dish.variations.length > 0){
        const url = '/dish/' + dish.dishId; 
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("Will render a modal");
                this.setState({
                    showModal: true,
                    modalContent: <Modal 
                            identifier={'modal-' + extraId}
                            show={true}
                            modalClose={this.closeModal}>
                            <Variations 
                                dish={res.data} 
                                extraIdentifier={extraId}
                            />
                            <br />
                            <div className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
                                <Button clicked={() => this.onIncrementMenuItemWithVariation(res.data, extraId)}>Lägg till</Button>
                            </div>
                        </Modal>,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error", error);
            });
    }else{
        this.onIncrementMenuItem(dish); 
    }
}
```

and in the components render method I simply display modalContent

```
    {this.state.modalContent}
```

The console.log "Will render a modal" is only called one time, but I got another log in the modal component which is called several times.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are setting `state` property `modalContent` 's value as JSX element and its not doing rendering for you. You are most likely relying on some other mechanism where you are outputting value of `modalContent` as `{modalContent}` or just passing it as a prop to something.

Comment: Why don't set show to false when modal is hidden and don't use state for storing all modal?

Comment: The problem is that I never know how many variations a dish could have. Therefore I need to render the modal dynamically after I fetch the dish. Don´t really know how to do that if not in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Remove modal content from the state and add to JSX in render something like this:

```
<>
    <other elements/>
    <Modal show={this.sate.showModal} modalClose={this.closeModal}>
                        .....
    </Modal>
</>
```

Comment: I never know how many variations a dish could have. So I don't really know how to render a modal dynamically using only JSX?